# Laravel POST not working in apache2

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am currently developing a web application using the Laravel framework, and using the php artisan serve  tool, I have checked that the links are working accordingly. I tested this under apache, and it did not work accordingly, so I set up mod rewrite enabled for the application, and now it works for all URLs which I type in browser in general.
However, whenever I try to handle POST routes, they are not handled at all, and I get 500 Internal Server Error in browser console. What are the possible solutions for this problem?

edit 1:- To further clarify the problem, all the routes I have used so far are working while using the test server provided by `php artisan serve`.

Therefore, here is my 000_default.conf for test :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Pass csrf token

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Which part of the code do you require @GauravDave ?

Comment: When you get 500 Server Error, Add what error you see in the Preview section of Inspect Element. Also, add your routes, controller, and view.

Comment: To be truthful, nothing at all. Rather, the 500 Internal server error comes from the browser console. This works with the laravel test server though, and not within the apache virtualhost itself.

Comment: A 500 internal server error always gets a line in the error log. Check that line for more info. Unless it's a PHP error and not an Apache error (which based on your description is unlikely)

Comment: @apokryfos I solved it. Thank you for your help. It was that the storage folder did not have the required permissions as shown in the error.log file

Answer (score 0):

Add this token in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: These I have done. I am referring to the fact that these wont work after I have set it up in apache server.